# How to Pass an array of Strings to PartitionBy

Tags: apache-spark

I am grouping by a dataset based on the value of a column `mynewmeancol2` like the following :

```
    dF.select("col0","col1","col2","col3","col4").where("col1> mynewmeancol2")
.withColumn("avgCol1", avg("col1").over(Window.partitionBy("col0", "col1")))
```

I want to know how to pass an array of **column** **NAMES** (MEANS **LIST OF STRING**) (instead of just `col0` & `col1`) to `partitionBy` ?

EDIT  : i saw that something like this inside `partitionBy` :

```
partitionsColumnsList.map(col(_)):_*)
```

would work in Scala. But i need it to be in JAVA.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you an pass, Instead of `Arrays.stream(df.columns())` you can replace with list of String(column names)

```
List<Column> arrayList = Arrays.stream(df.columns())
        .map(functions::col).collect(Collectors.toList());

WindowSpec window = Window.partitionBy(arrayList.toArray(new Column[arrayList.size()]));
```

Comment: For JAVA 8 (or JAVA11 ?) the conversion from List of Strings to List of Columns doesn't work, how to do it then ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can `unnest` the **array** and pass to **`partitionBy`** clause.

**`Example:`**

**Spark-Scala:**

```
df.show()
//+---+----+
//| id|dept|
//+---+----+
//|  1|   a|
//|  2|   a|
//|  3|   b|
//|  4|   c|
//+---+----+

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val cols=df.columns
val w_spec=Window.partitionBy(cols.head,cols.tail:_*)

df.withColumn("cc",avg("id").over(w_spec)).show()
//+---+----+---+
//| id|dept| cc|
//+---+----+---+
//|  2|   a|2.0|
//|  4|   c|4.0|
//|  3|   b|3.0|
//|  1|   a|1.0|
//+---+----+---+
```

**`Pyspark:`**

```
df.show()
#+---+----+
#| id|dept|
#+---+----+
#|  1|   a|
#|  2|   a|
#|  3|   b|
#|  4|   c|
#+---+----+

from pyspark.sql import window
cols=df.columns
w_spec=Window.partitionBy(*[cols])

df.withColumn("cc",avg("id").over(w_spec)).show()
#+---+----+---+
#| id|dept| cc|
#+---+----+---+
#|  2|   a|2.0|
#|  4|   c|4.0|
#|  1|   a|1.0|
#|  3|   b|3.0|
#+---+----+---+
```

Comment: i need to pass an array of strings, and in Java pls

Comment: ALso the array could contain less than the total number of column of a dataset

Comment: Question is "how to do this is Java". Not in pyspark or scala